# $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)=abc-101$ how to find all integer solutions for this one

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

I am working with the equation: $ab+bc+ac-a-b-c=100$. I need to find all integer solutions for this.
What I figure out for now is that I can turn it into $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)=abc-101$. But this does not help me to go further.

My questions are :  how to find all integer solutions. and is there a general category of this kind of questions? for example, finding integer solutions of linear equation system that the number of unknown is greater than the number of equations?

Comment: Mathematica finds 8 solutions $$\{\{a\to -1,b\to 39,c\to -9,d\to -519\},\{a\to -1,b\to 47,c\to -48,d\to -2401\},\{a\to 0,b\to 0,c\to -100,d\to 23\},\{a\to 0,b\to 0,c\to -100,d\to 43\},\{a\to 0,b\to 2,c\to 102,d\to -21\},\{a\to 0,b\to 2,c\to 102,d\to 0\},\{a\to 1,b\to 37,c\to -50,d\to 1901\},\{a\to 1,b\to 43,c\to 23,d\to -865\}\}$$ of the latter equation.

Comment: @user64494 what is $d$?

Comment: @user64494 thanks a lot. are there any general methods other than the final solutions?

Comment: These matematica solutions seem sus - $a = 1$ forces $bc = 101,$ which violates the last two.

Comment: Mathematica [gives 6 integer solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ab%2Bbc%2Bca+-+a+-+b+-c+%3D+100), but it is missing $(1, 1, 101)$ (and others).

Comment: $ab+bc+ac-a-b-c=100\implies (a + c - 1) (b + c - 1) = (101 - c + c^2)$. Let $c$ parameter, then find $a,b$ from divisors of $(101 - c + c^2)$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha shows $\,6\,$ solutions
[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ab%2Bbc%2Bac-a-b-c%3D100).

\begin{align*}
a = -6, b = -6, c = -4
\\a = -6, b = -4, c = -6
\\a = -4, b = -6, c = -6
\\a = 5, b = 7, c = 7
\\a = 7, b = 5, c = 7
\\a = 7, b = 7, c = 5
\end{align*}

Comment: @Halk, One of solutions is $(a,b,c)=(a, 2-a, a^2-2a+102)$ where $a$ is any integer.